# Open terminal / Run terminal apps with different shells

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, zsh

My default shell is zsh (with oh-my-zsh and other plugins) and everything works fine. On the other side I'd like to
-- have new menu, which opens "bash terminal" (gnome-terminal with runs bash shell)
-- open few apps (e.g. Midnight Commander) with bash shell.

I'm able to do 2) with env variable SHELL=BASH. Could someone explain me how to configure this please?? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The way a terminal emulator can be set to use a different shell than your default shell differs between terminal emulators.

For `gnome-terminal`, you can change the shell on the "Command" tab in the "Preferences" dialog. Check "Run a custom command instead of my shell" and specify the shell you want to run.

To achieve what you want, create a new profile and change the setting as in the previous paragraph. Then, you can launch `gnome-terminal` with that profile, and therefore with a different shell, using the `--profile=` option. For example, if you named the new profile "Custom", then you can launch `gnome-terminal` with that profile using the following command:

```
gnome-terminal --profile="Custom"
```

To open `gnome-terminal` and automatically open an application, for example `mc` (Midnight Commander), use the empty `--` at the end:

```
gnome-terminal --profile="Custom" -- mc
```

This will open the terminal emulator with `mc` loaded, and running on the custom shell you defined in the "Custom" profile.